# SQL AES_256 Encryption and Decryption

Tags: security, sql-server-2016, encryption

I have an odd encryption and decryption problem. Encryption worked fine in SQL 2008 R2, we were using TRIPLE_DES_3KEY. This has been deprecated in SQL 2016, so we were are testing out AES_256. My original string keeps getting cut off, not sure what it's doing or how else to explain. I am sure I'm missing something, but not sure what. Detals below. Thanks!

My Symmetric Key:

```
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SK03  
WITH  
    ALGORITHM = AES_256  
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'ThisIsMyAES_256EncryptionTest';
```

My Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_EncryptionTest](  
    [OriginalValue] [varchar](max) NULL,  
    [Encryptedvalue] [varbinary](8000) NULL  
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

My Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[_usp_EncryptionTest]  
    @InputString varchar(MAX),  
    @InputString2 varchar(MAX)  

AS  
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SK03 DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD='ThisIsMyAES_256EncryptionTest'  

    INSERT INTO _EncryptionTest
        (OriginalValue, Encryptedvalue)
    VALUES (
        @InputString
        ,ENCRYPTBYKEY(Key_GUID('SK03'), CONVERT(VARBINARY,@InputString2))
        )

    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SK03;

END
```

My Test SQL:

```
EXEC _usp_EncryptionTest 'Spring is Finally Here! Spring is Finally Here!','Spring is Finally Here! Spring is Finally Here!'
```

As you can see from the image below, the data gets updated to my table.

[image]

My Decryption SQL:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SK03 DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD='ThisIsMyAES_256EncryptionTest'  
SELECT   
    [OriginalValue]   
    ,CONVERT(varchar(MAX), DECRYPTBYKEY([EncryptedValue]))  
FROM  
    _EncryptionTest  
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SK03;
```

The image below should show the results with the decryoted value cutoff.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try defining the length of the `varbinary` in your convert statement as `varbinary(max).` Per https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362(v=sql.110).aspx it would default to 30.

You can replicate that with the following script:

```
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(100);
SELECT  @STRING = REPLICATE('X', 100);

SELECT  LEN(@STRING) AS String_Length,
        LEN(CONVERT(VARBINARY, @STRING)) AS Varbinary_Length ,
        LEN(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @STRING)) AS VarbinaryMax_Length;
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in ENCRYPTION PASSWORD. For AES 256 ENCRYPTION PASSWORD length should be 32.
use below code and check.

```
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SK03  
WITH  
    ALGORITHM = AES_256  
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzasdefb'; 
go
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_EncryptionTest](  
    [OriginalValue] [varchar](max) NULL,  
    [Encryptedvalue] [varbinary](max) NULL  
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
go
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[_usp_EncryptionTest]  
    @InputString varchar(MAX),  
    @InputString2 varchar(MAX)  

AS  
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SK03 DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzasdefb'  

    INSERT INTO _EncryptionTest
        (OriginalValue, Encryptedvalue)
    VALUES (
        @InputString
        ,ENCRYPTBYKEY(Key_GUID('SK03'), CONVERT(VARBINARY(max),@InputString2))
        )

    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SK03;

END  
go
EXEC _usp_EncryptionTest 'Spring is Finally Here! Spring is Finally Here!','Spring is Finally Here! Spring is Finally Here!'
go
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SK03 DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzasdefb'  
SELECT   
    [OriginalValue] ,
    CONVERT(varchar(MAX), DECRYPTBYKEY([EncryptedValue]))
FROM  
    _EncryptionTest  
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SK03;
```